# If two fields which are extensions of the rationals are equal, can elements be adjoined and preserve equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question is pretty general, but suppose that I have fields $\mathbb{Q}(a) = \mathbb{Q}(b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are not equal to one another.

Does it hold then that

$$
\mathbb{Q}(ca) = \mathbb{Q}(cb)?
$$

where $c$ can be any element?  Or does it only hold for certain conditions on $c$?

Comment: Any element of what? $\mathbb{Q}$? $\mathbb{Q}(a)$?

Comment: Well, anything really.  I suppose an element of the complex numbers.

Comment: Take $w=\exp(2\pi i/3)$, $a=w$, $b=w^2$ and $c=w^{-1}$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(a)=\mathbb{Q}(b)$ but the same is not true adding $ca=1$ and $cb=w$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it need not be true in general. Let $\zeta_3$ be a primitive cubic root of unity. Then $\zeta_3^2$ is also a primitive cubic root of unity, so $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2)$. So we can take $a=\zeta_3$, $b=\zeta_3^2$.

But if $c=\zeta_3$, then $\mathbb{Q}(ca) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2)$, while $\mathbb{Q}(cb) = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^3) = \mathbb{Q}(1) = \mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2)\neq\mathbb{Q}$, you need not get equality.

It certainly holds if $c\in\mathbb{Q}$: if $c=0$ then both extensions are $\mathbb{Q}$; and if $c\neq 0$, then $\mathbb{Q}(ca)=\mathbb{Q}(a) = \mathbb{Q}(b)=\mathbb{Q}(cb)$.

Comment: Is there any known criteria for when this equality will hold and when it won't?  If so, could you point me towards a reference?

Comment: Or perhaps if you can show that the product $ca$ or $cb$ is never an rational number?

Comment: @BillyBob: That does not suffice either. Take $a=\zeta_3\sqrt[3]{2}$, $b=\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{4}$, and $c=\zeta_3$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(cb)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{4})$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{Q}(ca)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2\sqrt[3]{2})$ is not.